# Algorithm for adjust image scale to browser sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, algorithm

I need a algorithm/mathematical calculation of CSS `background`.
When we are writing styles for our page and sometimes we use background-image for element background styles and syntax is like this: `background: url('img.jpg') center top;` This style provide browser to change background image sizes automatically when browser sizes will be changed and also we can see only center side of our styled element.
But maybe we need a image(in my case), without background property, like this: `<img src="img.jpg">`. The last one following example is my problem. I want to change it automatically and will be shown only center side of image like a css's background property.
And now, I'm thinking to solve this problem using javascript, but I need a algorithm from browser. How it can adjust image size with browsers sizes and how it can show only center side of image...

So I mean how to get same result in javascript from `background-position:center;`

I hope you understand what I want...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x9Ev5/)?

html:

```
full image:<br/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"></img><br/>
smaller, centered image:<br/>
<div class="container"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"></img></div>
```

css:

```
.container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container img{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Css can achieve a lot, you dont always have to go for js. If you want to change the image, you only have to change the margin-left/margin-top properties to half the image's width/height.